# Best way of binding onchange event on every form field using Rails 3, UJS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, onchange, jquery-events

I want to make form submission on every `onchange()` form field event to get "live search results count" in separate css box. (Like [here](http://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?scopeId=C&lang=en) when you change some form field value you get immediate "search results count" change in the right CSS box).

What's the best way (easiest) of doing this?

**PS**. question is about technique, because I know how to do this "manually", but I have 10+ fields of different types (select/select-multiple/checkbox) and it's not handy to work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input, select').change(function() {
    var params = {};
    params[this.name] = this.value;
    $.post('yourFieldHandlingUrl.rb', params);
});
```

of course this is minimalistic, you can add ajax success/error handling.

For your cars example, this mean the status of other boxes is stored on the server, in the session usually. Else you can get possilbes combinations inside javascript at the build of the page. But the best way is surely to sends **all** inputs to re-count the value. This is easily done with something like this:

```
$('input, select').change(function() {
    var params = {};
    $(this).closest('div.inputsContainer').each( function () {
        params[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    $.post('yourFieldHandlingUrl.rb', params);
});
```